# How to use mgt-people-picker in react framework

Tags: reactjs, spfx, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I'm trying to use `mgt-people-picker` inside my SPFx Webpart with React framework, and couldn't get the `selected-people` attribute work. I tried passing an array of graph user objects to it but no luck.

When I tried to use

```
document.querySelector('mgt-people-picker').selectUsersById(["id","id"])
```

it threw an error saying `"Property 'selectUsersById' does not exist on type 'Element'"`

The documentation is quite limited and unclear and there isn't much reference that I could find. Can anyone tell me how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React passes all data to web components in the form of HTML attributes. For primitive data this is fine, but it does not work when passing rich data, like objects or arrays. In those cases you will need to use a ref to pass in the object. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/overview#react)

Here is an example setting the users by id:

```
export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component<IHelloWorldProps, {}> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IHelloWorldProps> {
    return (
      <mgt-people-picker ref="peoplePicker"></mgt-people-picker>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.refs.peoplePicker) {
      let peoplePicker = this.refs.peoplePicker as MgtPeoplePicker;

      peoplePicker.addEventListener('selectionChanged', e => console.log(peoplePicker.selectedPeople));

      peoplePicker.selectUsersById(['4782e723-f4f4-4af3-a76e-25e3bab0d896']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, please accept the answer so others can find it easier

Answer (score 0):

With React, you can use PeoplePicker from the @microsoft/mgt-react module. Here is an example:

```
  <PeoplePicker
    selectionMode="single"
    defaultSelectedUserIds={[Inky@pathto.onmicrosoft.com"}]}
    selectionChanged={onChangePeople}
  />
```

And the event handler:

```
  function onChangePeople(e) {
    console.log(e.detail);
  }
```

Comment: the `selectionChanged` is not triggered in my case