# How to use the Microsoft Graph mgt-people-picker component in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm new in Microsoft Graph API. I'm trying to develop a proof of concept .NET core MVC Web App, which one of the functionality is to have people-picker to search user from Azure AD.

Following is how I did:

```
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@@microsoft/mgt/dist/bundle/mgt-loader.js'></script>


`<mgt-msal-provider client-id="[Removed]"
               login-type="redirect"
               scopes="user.read,people.read"
               redirect-uri="[Removed]"
               authority="[Removed]"></mgt-msal-provider>`

`<mgt-people-picker></mgt-people-picker>`
```

I have configured below information based on Microsoft documentation:

```
`"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "[Removed]",
"ClientId": "[Removed]",
"TenantId": "[Removed]",
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"}`
```

Somehow it does not able to search my Azure AD users, its always should not match is found.
But when i try to use     `<mgt-mock-provider></mgt-mock-provider>`, i can see a list of users.

Is there any workable example that someone can show to me or guide me to a correct direction to let me find out the answer I need.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What document are you referring to? And please share the code of searching Azure AD users.

Comment: I'm trying to do people-picker function within .NET Core MVC by following this example https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/people-picker?WT.mc_id=quickbitesdev-blog-aycabas ,  however, I can't figure it out how to do it. Above is the code that I'm using to load the people picker function from Microsoft Graph API. but it is not working.

Comment: Have you looked at the react implementation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60368108/how-to-use-mgt-people-picker-in-react-framework?

Comment: @Dev Yes, but are this the only way to make it work? I prefer to look for .NET Core MVC example. I also not sure how to convert it to MVC type for that. Any example that I can further refer?  I prefer solution used in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172718/how-to-get-input-values-from-mgt-people-picker-when-a-form-is-submitted

Comment: @Henry you're asking about a *Javascript component*, not the Graph API. It doesn't matter what the backend technology is, that component runs on the browser. You can use it in an ASP.NET Core or a static HTML file, it doesn't matter. Just include the necessary Javascript libraries in the page

Comment: @Henry the docs for the [MSAL provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/providers/msal) and the [Build a web application with the Microsoft Graph Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/build-a-web-app) guide show that only `ClientID` is required. Have you tried excluding the other attributes? Have you logged in in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a login operation.

Please add `<mgt-login></mgt-login>`.

I download the sample code from the [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph) you shared.

After configuring it by following the steps in that link, I added the following code into `Index.cshtml` file.

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@@microsoft/mgt/dist/bundle/mgt-loader.js"></script>
    <mgt-msal-provider client-id="{client id}"
                       login-type="redirect"
                       scopes="user.read,people.read"
                       redirect-uri="https://localhost:44321/"
                       authority="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my tenant}.onmicrosoft.com"></mgt-msal-provider>
    <mgt-login></mgt-login>
    <mgt-people-picker></mgt-people-picker>
</div>
```

`appsettings.json` is like this:

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "{my tenant}.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "{tenant id}",
    "ClientId": "{client id}",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc",
    // To call an API
    "ClientSecret": "{client secret}"
  },
```

After I sign in, the home page is like this:

[image]

Comment: you are right, after I adding login operation, i was able to get it working. Another thing is i also using wrong domain url, which also one of the reason, when i trying all the possibilities, it is not working. Another question, if without using the login operation, it is possible to get it work? I actually implementing Single Sign On, which user login information is already there. It is possible?

Comment: @Henry I am not very clear about this. But I think you should take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/providers/custom

Comment: @'Allen Wu' Thanks for the help. I will further exploring about that. thanks again. Just update you beside above changes, i also have adding new API permission: People.Read (With admin consent), ClientSecret, and signout url.
Thanks for the help again